# Grunt contrib jasmine shows error but not fail the build

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, npm, jasmine

I'm trying to debug whether `grunt-contrib-jasmine` caused the issue or `phantomjs` I have some failure in my codebase but grunt doesn't report as failure

```
Running "jasmine:dev" (jasmine) task
Testing jasmine specs via PhantomJS

>> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(document).foundation1()') at
>> assets/js/build/theme-bundle.js:1203
>> js-tests/vendors/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
>> js-tests/vendors/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
>> js-tests/vendors/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2
>> js-tests/vendors/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2 J
...........................................................

59 specs in 0.287s.
>> 0 failures

Running "phplint:files" (phplint) task

Done, without errors.
```

Here's my Gruntfile.js

```
jasmine: {
            dev: {
                src : ['assets/js/build/*.js'],
                options: {
                    specs: 'js-tests/build/specs.js',
                    outfile: '_SpecRunner.html',
                    display: 'short',
                    summary: true,
                    styles : [
                        'assets/css/theme.css'
                    ],
                    vendor: [
                        'js-tests/vendors/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js',
                        'js-tests/vendors/underscore/underscore-min.js',
                        'js-tests/vendors/backbone/backbone-min.js',
                        'assets/vendor/foundation/vendor/topbar.js',
                        'assets/vendor/foundation/vendor/reveal.js',
                        'assets/vendor/foundation/js/foundation.js',
                        'assets/vendor/foundation/js/vendor/modernizr.js',
                        'assets/vendor/foundation/js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js',
                        'assets/vendor/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie-1.4.1.min.js',
                        'assets/vendor/slick/*.js',
                        'js-tests/vendors/wordpress/wp-util.js',
                        'js-tests/vendors/stub/global.js',
                        'js-tests/vendors/stub/facebook.js',
                        'js-tests/vendors/stub/mandrill.js',
                        'js-tests/vendors/wordpress/tinymce.min.js',
                        'js-tests/vendors/jasmine-jquery/jasmine-jquery.js'
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
```

And here's the dependencies

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-core": "^5.2.0",
    "browserify": "^8.1.3",
    "browserify-shim": "3.8.7",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-browserify": "^3.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jasmine": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.5.3",
    "grunt-grunticon": "^1.6.0",
    "grunt-pagespeed": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-postcss": "^0.5.1",
    "grunt-sass": "~0.18.0",
    "grunt-scss-lint": "^0.3.4",
    "grunt-strip-css-comments": "^1.1.0",
    "mochify": "^2.1.0",
    "phantomjs": "1.9.17",
    "phplint": "^1.2.0",
    "remapify": "2.0.0"
  },
```

Comment: Can you show code around `assets/js/build/theme-bundle.js:1203`

Comment: It's `$(document).foundation1()` I purposely break that just to see how Jasmine behaves. Because we had a case like this and we didn't realized because our CI couldn't catch that.

Comment: I assume that the code is not inside spec but inside application code.

Comment: You are correct which i assume that Jasmine would flag that

Comment: Well I tried every possible scenario, and it does fail in my case. I even tried with onerror handler , works for that too. Any more information you might want to add. Well I was using karma. Have to check with grunt.